# My jquery code does not run in any browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, document-ready

my jquery is not working in any browser i reffered many answers on web for it none helped me out..!!

This is my code
in the index file i tried in both 
(index.html) and (index.php)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Jquery</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="message" style="display:none;"> Welcome to my site</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fade.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

the javascript files were in js folder.

And the fade.js code was :-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#message').fadeIn('slow'); 
});
```

and the jquery code was which i downloaded from jquery website
i tried the production both versions 1 and 2
and also other source links like

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

also jquery source links which some users uses.
also i tried to shift the script code above the  tags.
but whatever it is i tried not working in any browsers.

Please Help me out guys...!!

Comment: You need to swap the script. jQuery must be loaded first. Put both in the head and spell function correctly too

Comment: Copy the code from here and paste it in your document and see if this works: http://jsfiddle.net/11nonnea/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fucntion` should be `function` & load the `jQuery` before your script.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function() {
                  /*^^^^^^*/
    $('#message').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: Well spotted... but jQuery also needs to be loaded before it is used

Comment: oops i  got a typo thanx but still after editing its still not getting

Answer (score 1):

You have to load jQuery **before** you try to call functions it provides. Swap the order of your script tags.

Then look at your JavaScript error console. It will be complaining that you have misspelt `function` as `fucntion`.

Comment: With your rep you can close too. Not worth an answer

Comment: ya i corrected fucntion and swapped the script still not opening in my browsers :(

Answer (score 0):

Just copy/paste this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Jquery</title>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#message').fadeIn('slow'); 
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="message" style="display:none;"> Welcome to my site</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its not working when i add it externally please help me out..!!

Comment: @sagarkargathra you want to add the script in an external js file? Do you have anything else in that file? Or just this one script?